# colocar una imagen a Label en javaFx

Tags: java, javafx, imagen

quisiera ponerle una imagen a un `label` de la bibloteca Fx. lo he intentado pero no encuentro algún método que tega esta función.

```
Label label= new Label();
label.setBackgraund();
```

Comment: Te recomiendo esta librería [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/).

Comment: si me puedes dar un poco mas de detalles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahora mismo no puedo darte un ejemplo usando ControlsFX.

Pero puedes hacerlo también sin necesidad de dicha librería del siguiente modo:

```
Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("tuImagen.jpg")); 
Label myLabel = new Label("Texto Label"); 
myLabel.setGraphic(new ImageView(image));
```

Por supuesto el archivo de imagen debe estar en la carpeta de tu proyecto.

Puedes ver más detalles en la [documentación de Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/label.htm).

Comment: muchas gracias a usted por el favor